# What's the proper way to get smtpd (OpenSMTPD) to pick up changes to smtpd.conf?

Tags: openbsd, smtpd, opensmtpd

I'm new to OpenBSD and in the process of learning OpenSMTPD. I would have expected some sort of "restart" option from the `smtpctl` command, but it only has a `stop` with no `start` which might force a reread of `smtpd.conf` so changes take effect. Outside of rebooting the server, is the correct approach to kill `smtpd` followed by executing `/etc/rc.d/smtpd` somehow in the background? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
/etc/rc.d/smtpd restart
```

If that doesn't work, go for

```
/etc/rc.d/smtpd stop
/etc/rc.d/smtpd start
```

Comment: don't forget **rcctl(8)**. I believe that is now the encouraged method, although functionally it is pretty much the same thing